# C++11: Example of difference between ordinary string literal and UTF-8 string literal?

Tags: c++, utf-8, character-encoding, c++11, string-literals

> A string literal that does not begin with an encoding-prefix is an ordinary string
>   literal, and is initialized with the given characters.
>
> A string literal that begins with u8, such as u8"asdf", is a UTF-8 string literal and is initialized with the given characters as encoded in UTF-8.

I don't understand the difference between an ordinary string literal and a UTF-8 string literal.

Can someone provide an example of a situation where they are different?  (Cause different compiler output)

(I mean from the POV of the standard, not any particular implementation)

> Each source character set member in a character literal or a string literal, as well as each escape
>   sequence and universal-character-name in a character literal or a non-raw string literal, is converted to
>   the corresponding member of the execution character set.

Comment: An ordinary string literal is in whatever encoding the compiler likes best; an UTF-8 string literal is encoded in UTF-8 (as mandated by the standard).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: What do you mean "the compiler likes best" ? When you say it is "encoded in X", do you mean in the source file or in the executable?

Comment: In the program. The standard knows not about executables.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: So you are saying it overrides the execution character set from translation phase 5?

Comment: No. The execution character set is "the encoding the compiler likes best". It does not have to be UTF-8. Example: `std::cout << int("A"[0]);` can print 193 (EBCDIC, for example) while `static_assert(u8"A"[0] == 0x41, "");` is an assertion that cannot fail.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: So whatever the execution character set is, a UTF-8 string literal will always be __output__ in UTF-8, so at run-time it appears as UTF-8 encoded to the generated program?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: On the EBCDIC system what will `std::cout << int(u8"A"[0])` print?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: In practice, are any major compilers *not* using UTF-8? (Microsoft's?)

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: You can override the execution (and source) character set in gcc with options to the compiler, but the default is UTF-8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C and C++ languages allow a huge amount of latitude in their implementations.  C was written long before UTF-8 was "the way to encode text in single bytes": different systems had different text encodings.

So what the byte values are for a string in C and C++ are really up to the compiler.  `'A'` is whatever the compiler's chosen encoding is for the character `A`, which may not agree with UTF-8.

C++ has added the requirement that real UTF-8 string literals must be supported by compilers.  The bit value of `u8"A"[0]` is fixed by the C++ standard through the UTF-8 standard, regardless of the preferred encoding of the platform the compiler is targeting.

Now, much as most platforms C++ targets use 2's complement integers, most compilers have character encodings that are mostly compatible with UTF-8.  So for strings like `"hello world"`, `u8"hello world"` will almost certainly be identical.

For a concrete example, from `man gcc`

> -fexec-charset=charset
>
> Set the execution character set, used for string and character constants. The default is UTF-8. charset can be any encoding supported by the system's iconv library routine.
>
> -finput-charset=charset
>
> Set the input character set, used for translation from the character set of the input file to the source character set used by GCC. If the locale does not specify, or GCC cannot get this information from the locale, the default is UTF-8. This can be overridden by either the locale or this command line option. Currently the command line option takes precedence if there's a conflict. charset can be any encoding supported by the system's iconv library routine.

is an example of being able to change the execution and input character sets of C/C++.

Comment: So to clarify, the u8 prefix effects the execution character set used when generating the string literal as a char array during translation phase 5.  The u8 prefix has no effect on the input character set used to read the string literal during translation phase 1.

Comment: @user1131467 I believe so, at a beer-bet level.  Because the input charset could in theory mean what your input-charset aware editor displays as `"` is the utf-8 code for `+`, and the compiler reads it as `"`.  Ie, the bytes in the source file only make any sense at all in the context of the input charset for the compiler.  It would be an interesting bit of obfuscated programming to write a seemingly legal C/C++ program that actually does something completely different because of the input charset used to compile it.